# Angularjs and apache rewrite doesn't work on subfolder

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use `AngularJs` with `html5mode` enabled, and to be able to use it i need to enable a `rewrite` i need an `.htaccess` to point to the folder.

When going to the root `index`, there is no problem, everything works fine. But when i try to redirect to a subfolder where there is another section, i keep getting errors. For example, i have an admin section to publish news, etc.. So to access this portion of the app i need to go to a subfolder called `/adm` like this `www.site.com/adm` and this is where the errors starts.

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is the errors I'm getting:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When looking further, i see this is point to the index on the root. I know it has something to do with the `.htaccess` file, but i don't how to create a rule to identify if it's a root folder or sub folder and create the proper rewrite rule.

Comment: did you add a base href to your html file? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links

Comment: @Ronnie Yes. the base is `/adm` also tried `/adm/`

Comment: What is supposed to happen inside `/adm` ? Should the rewrite work inside that folder? If so, what is the expected result? Yes, right now everything that is not existing file or folder gets rewritten into index.html in root

Comment: @poncha it's a whole new section. For example, i have the web site on the root, and when accessing the `/adm` it's a new section only for admins, to manage the website. So this subfolder will have it's own index, folders, views, etc.. The rewrite needs to happen on this directory as well (i think) because it also need to have html5mode enabled in order to remove the `#` from the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(adm/)?index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(adm/)?. /$1index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

What this does is rewrite everything inside `/adm/` to `/adm/index.html` and everything else to `/index.html`